# Typesetting acceptance of spacing slashes?

Tags: typesetting

In UI design, one often has to work in the confines of limited space and/or simply try to reduce overly excessive descriptions and such.

Often, this results in using slashes a lot. This/that type of thing.

I've been asked in the past to add spaces to each side of a slash to give it some 'breathing' room and while at first this seemed wrong, I've also grown to prefer it as an option.

An example:

```
Download/Print PDF
```

vs.

```
Download / Print PDF
```

Some questions:

- Do you prefer one over the other (and why?)
- Is the spaced-slash acceptable? Am I committing a typographic faux pas?

Ideally, one would kern/letterspace the slash and not use whole spaces, but in the context of web dev, it's likely that rarely will out content folks and/or developers spend time on that detail, so am proposing the spaced option. It also offers the added benefit of being more likely to wrap properly if need be.

Answer (score 7):

As it often goes with these things, the answer will be subjective. Here are some thoughts, though:

I think I tend to go without a space unless I'm worried about things flowing to multiple lines.

Perhaps context could help you decide. Maybe 'Download/Print PDF' carries a connotation of 'Download PDF and Print PDF' while 'Download / Print PDF' says 'Download and Print PDF'.

Maybe, if possible, you could try using `&thinsp;` to use a [thin space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_Space) to strike a better balance:

Download / Print PDF (space)
Download / Print PDF (thin space)
Download/Print PDF (no space)

Hair space (`&#8239;`) should be in the mix too, but didn't seem to look any different when I tried it here. [There are a few other space options in Unicode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) as well, but I don't think any others are relevant to this discussion.

Comment: Good point on the slight variance in potential meaning. It's subtle, and sometimes not that important, but good to know. I do like the thinspace. Alas, getting content authors and developers to adhere to that kind of detail has been proven hard to police in my experience, so am trying to keep the 'rule' simple as possible.

Comment: I've always seen a slash rendered as "or", but I do get a sense that people use the spaces as you've said to group the associations.

Answer (score 5):

I use a full space whenever possible and feasible.

As Brendan states in his answer, it is highly subjective.

I feel the full space simply makes it much clearer and easier to read that it's an either / or situation.

However, when using the slashes in a file or directory path, I don't use the space in order to designate a continuous path. For obvious reasons - users may include a space mistakenly.

I never interpret the slash as "and" as Brendan states. It's always "or" or a directory path in my mind.

Comment: Interesting point about file path and/or URLs. Perhaps that is an argument TO add the space when working in the context of web sites, where you are going to also see a lot of URLs and not want spaces there.

Answer (score 5):

Augh! No, no, no, no, no. No spaces. Kerning is the correct answer. Adding spaces introduces the possibility for error, bad breaks, and misinterpretation. When two items which must be connected are separated by artificial spaces, you are breaking the required connections. If it bothers you visually that much, change the slash to "and" (Download and Print) and have done with it.

I am both a typesetter and editor/proofreader, so there are no instances where I would allow spaces around slashes. Ever.

Comment: Well okay then :)

Comment: Kerning is the correct answer in print, where I'm the one typesetting. Alas, this is web, where I, for better or worse, rarely am the one actually formatting the HTML content. In fact, being able to kern a particular character is likely impossible in the corporate web dev workflow :(

Comment: Note that download&thinsp;/&thinsp;print is NOT "ctrl+f and type" searchable unless one a) knows the alt codes; and b) recognizes the space is not a regular space.

Comment: @DA01 I understand that kerning doesn't work for web. But on the web, there's the chance the font/size etc. are going to be overridden anyway. You simply can't control HTML text 100%. The best solution is to have the fewest moving parts. Adding spaces adds moving parts. It adds openings for errors to be introduced. You don't want to make a web dev workflow more complicated unnecessarily.

Comment: I would regard a slash surrounded by spaces as having a different meaning from a non-space-delimited slash.  In particular, if there is no space around the slash, I would interpret it as joining only the words immediately to either side; adding spaces would suggest that the slash is "further reaching".  Using a slash-with-spaces might be viewed similarly to hyphen-with-spaces where one really should use an em-dash (and no spaces), but I'm not sure there's a widely-recognized variation of the slash for such cases.

Comment: @supercat "hyphen-with-spaces" is wrong too, for the same reasons. If you want to combine two compound items with a slash, use hyphens or quote marks. *Far-reaching/deep-sounding*, for example.

Comment: Sometimes hyphens may sometimes be syntactically significant and quotations may be awkward.  Describing a tool with a 5/8" head on one end and a 3/4" head on the other as a 1/2" / 5/8" tool may be clearer than adding parentheses, quotes, or other punctuation.  Note that saying one needs a 1/2" / 5/8" wrench would be different from saying one needs a 1/2" wrench and a 5/8" wrench (some jobs might require the use of both simultaneously).

Comment: @supercat I follow your example, but for that case I'd use an en-dash (or an em-dash depending on how it looked): *a 1/2"–5/8" wrench* or *a 1/2"—5/8" wrench*. Or I'd just rewrite the sentence: *You need a specialized spanner for this job: a wrench with a 1/2" head on one end and a 5/8" head on the other.* Three slashes in a row is simply too confusing.

Comment: @supercat Additionally, if you're using InDesign or similar, there is a specialized fraction bar character which allows for super- and subscripted numbers, so that would make the fractions clearer and allow for the use of the slash (still without spaces).

Comment: If a procedure will require one wrench, describing it as words will probably be helpful.  If it will need more than one, having a shorter notation once the concept is introduced may be helpful, especially for informal on-line writing where it's hard to predict what fonts or glyphs people will have available.  An en-dash might be good, but only if the procedure didn't need any adjustable wrenches.  My point is that in some cases adding spaces around slashes may be semantically helpful.

Comment: @supercat We'll just have to agree to disagree, then. I will never see those spaces as helpful; they will *always* look wrong and distracting to me. Even online.